# NGINX server running FLASK on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, nginx, flask, raspberry-pi, uwsgi

I am trying to run a flask application with NGINX server on Pi Model 3B+. The code in the directory /home/pi/api/api.py. I am following this article
https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2018/12/running-flask-under-nginx-raspberry-pi/

My WSGI ini file

```
[uwsgi]
chdir = /home/pi/api
module = api:app

master = true
processes = 1
threads = 2

uid = www-data
gid = www-data

socket = /tmp/api.sock
chmod-socket = 664
vacuum = true
```

My uwsgi proxy after removing defaults

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/api_proxy
```

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name localhost;

location / { try_files $uri @app; }
location @app {
include uwsgi_params;
uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/api.sock;
}
}
```

My uwsgi.service file

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI Service
After=network.target

[Service]
User=www-data
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/flasktest/
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/uwsgi --ini /home/pi/api/uwsgi.ini

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But when I start the server using

```
sudo systemctl status uwsgi.service
```

I get this error

```
uwsgi.service - uWSGI Service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/uwsgi.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2020-04-22 02:58:37 IST; 51min ago
 Main PID: 464 (uwsgi)
    Tasks: 3 (limit: 2319)
   Memory: 13.5M
   CGroup: /system.slice/uwsgi.service
           ├─464 /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --ini /home/pi/api/uwsgi.ini
           └─728 /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --ini /home/pi/api/uwsgi.ini

Apr 22 03:40:32 websync uwsgi[464]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
Apr 22 03:40:32 websync uwsgi[464]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 724, in exec_module
Apr 22 03:40:32 websync uwsgi[464]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 859, in get_code
Apr 22 03:40:32 websync uwsgi[464]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 916, in get_data
Apr 22 03:40:32 websync uwsgi[464]: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: './api.py'
Apr 22 03:40:32 websync uwsgi[464]: unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
Apr 22 03:40:32 websync uwsgi[464]: *** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
Apr 22 03:40:32 websync uwsgi[464]: *** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
Apr 22 03:40:32 websync uwsgi[464]: gracefully (RE)spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 464)
Apr 22 03:40:32 websync uwsgi[464]: spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 728, cores: 2)
```

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that UWSGI does not have permission to access the file api.py. From your configuration, UWSGI is running with the user and group www-data. Check that that user or group has at least read permissions on that file.

As an aside, unless you need some of the capabilities of nginx (certificate handling, multiple concurrent connections, very fast response times for static files, or some other features), you could eliminate nginx and UWSGI and have that much less to worry about. If this is going to be a public-facing server, then yes, keep on your route. But if this is some private device with a simple web interface, eliminate complexity.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes, I need ssl on my flask api, so I am using the NGINX web server. Can you show me how to read and change permission for the file?

Comment: `ls -l api.py` will show you the file permissions, owner, and group. `chmod` allows you to change the permissions of a file you have write access to. `chown` and `chrgp` allow you to change the owner and group of a file, respectively. More information on these commands and others is available in the system manual pages. (`man chmod`, `man ls`, `man chown`, etc.)